# Parse string to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I get this string on my controller:

```
"[{\"id\":12},{\"id\":2,\"children\":[{\"id\":3},{\"id\":4}]}]"
```

I want to parse this, and create one foreach inside other foreach to get the parents and children.

I've been trying this:

```
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuJson>(json);
```

where MenuJson is:

```
public class MenuJson
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public List<string> children { get; set; }
}
```

I got this erro:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'AIO.Controllers.AdminMenuController+MenuJson' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.

And I tried other approach:

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
foreach (var property in objects)
{
    var id = property.Value;
    foreach (var innerProperty in ((JObject)property.Value).Properties())
    {
        var child = property.Value;
    }
}
```

Both I got errors when I try to convert the string.

My question is, How can I make this working?

And for my string, which approach is the best for my needs?

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
public class MenuJson
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public List<MenuJson> children { get; set; }
}

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuJson>>(json);
```

Comment: Yes, I've just tried, I got the same error, see my edit for the error

Comment: @bramalho, I think the problem is that you are trying to put into an OBJECT (single), a COLLECTION (because your JSON is a collection).

Try my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an working example:

```
public void Test()
    {
        string json = "[{\"id\":12},{\"id\":2,\"children\":[{\"id\":3},{\"id\":4}]}]";

        var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuJson>>(json);

        foreach (var property in objects)
        {
            var id = property.id;
            foreach (var child in property.children)
            {
                //child
            }
        }
    }
```